# Ocultar y mostrar JPanel, incluso el espacio ocupado (Swing)

Tags: java, java-swing, jpanel

Cuento con esta interfaz en Java Swing:

[image: GUI]

Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando se presione en "OCULTAR", se oculte el PANEL y también se elimine el espaciado ocupado y que cuando presione "MOSTRAR", me muestre nuevamente el PANEL.

He intentado con `setVisible()`, pero solo lo oculta y el espacio se mantiene.

Aquí dejo el codigo generado por netbeans, disculpen si no es lo adecuado :c

```
 package gui;

public class Ejemplo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Ejemplo() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("PANEL"));

    jLabel1.setText("NOMBRE:");

    jLabel2.setText("APELLIDOS:");

    jLabel3.setText("EDAD");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(52, 52, 52)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 310, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 310, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(216, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(42, 42, 42)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(147, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 145, 193));

    jButton2.setText("MOSTRAR");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("OCULTAR");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(173, 173, 173)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addGap(134, 134, 134)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addContainerGap(41, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    getContentPane().add(jPanel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    pack();
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejemplo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejemplo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejemplo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejemplo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Ejemplo().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;

 }
```

He intentado incluso eliminando la instancia y todo eso, creando una instancia afuera o usando `updateUI()` o `repaint()`, y nada.

En este ejemplo el Layout es `GridLayout`, pero si funciona con ese o *FreeDesign*, me parece bien.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ayudarte usando el metodo `pack()` el cual redimensiona el *frame* basándose en los tamaños de los componentes en cuestión; eso sugiere que si se hace invisible el componente `jPanel1` entonces la ventana se ajustara solo al tamaño del `jPanel2`.

Cada que se oculte y muestre el `JPanel` se llama a `pack()`:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  jPanel1.setVisible(false);
  pack();
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  jPanel1.setVisible(true);
  pack();
}
```

Solo por una cuestión de consistencia gráfica en el ancho de la ventana, para este caso, agrega un `addGap(220,220,220)` en el bloque de código:

```
.addGap(173, 173, 173)
.addComponent(jButton2)
.addGap(134, 134, 134)
.addComponent(jButton1)
.addGap(220, 220, 220)  //Justo aqui
.addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió. :)